# LINQ with reflection for nested property values

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection, propertyinfo

I'm looking to create a Linq Where, based on a nested property.

Let's say this is my project:

```
public class Car {
    public Engine Engine { get; set; }
}

public class Engine {
    public int HorsePower { get; set; }
}

var myCar = new Car() {
    Engine = new Engine() {
        HorsePower = 400
    }
};
```

I use this code found somewhere, which allow to create Expression,

```
private Expression<Func<TItem, bool>> PropertyEquals<TItem, TValue>( PropertyInfo property, TValue value ) {
    var param = Expression.Parameter( typeof( TItem ) );
    var memberExp = Expression.Property( param, property );

    BinaryExpression body;

    //If nullable, Expression.Equal won't work even if the value is not null. So we convert to non nullable (the compared expression)
    Type typeIfNullable = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType( memberExp.Type );
    if ( typeIfNullable != null ) {
        var convertedExp = Expression.Convert( memberExp, Expression.Constant( value ).Type );
        body = Expression.Equal( convertedExp, Expression.Constant( value ) );
    } else {
        body = Expression.Equal( memberExp, Expression.Constant( value ) );
    }

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TItem, bool>>( body, param );
}
```

Now, I had like to have an equivalent, calling my method PropertyEquals

```
var engine = myCar.Select( c => c.Engine.HorsePower == 400 );
```

Something like

```
var property = GetPropertyForDotSequence( typeof( Car ), "Engine.HorsePower" );
.Select( PropertyEquals<TEntity, int>( property , 400 ) );
```

I found a method which allow to find property based on a dotted format (GetPropertyForDotSequence), which work properly, but return HorsePower property info, and not Engine.HorsePower, so I get an error saying Car doesnot have an int32 property called HorsePower.

```
private PropertyInfo GetPropertyForDotSequence ( Type baseType, string propertyName ) {
        var parts = propertyName.Split( '.' );

        return ( parts.Length > 1 )
            ? GetPropertyForDotSequence( baseType.GetProperty( parts[ 0 ] ).PropertyType, parts.Skip( 1 ).Aggregate( ( a, i ) => a + "." + i ) )
            : baseType.GetProperty( propertyName );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve your goal, instead of using a separate helper function to extract the **last** property info from a property path and then passing the property info to your function, all that should be done inside the function itself, i.e. it should receive the `string` containing the property path like this

```
public static partial class Utils
{
    public static Expression<Func<TItem, bool>> PropertyEquals<TItem, TValue>(string propertyPath, TValue value)
    {
        var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TItem), "source");
        var propertyNames = propertyPath.Split('.');
        var member = Expression.Property(source, propertyNames[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < propertyNames.Length; i++)
            member = Expression.Property(member, propertyNames[i]);
        Expression left = member, right = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue));
        if (left.Type != right.Type)
        {
            var nullableType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(left.Type);
            if (nullableType != null)
                right = Expression.Convert(right, left.Type);
            else
                left = Expression.Convert(left, right.Type);
        }
        var body = Expression.Equal(left, right);
        var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<TItem, bool>>(body, source);
        return expr;
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure how it can be useful though because the signature does not allow inferring the generic types, so it would require something like this

```
var predicate = Utils.PropertyEquals<Car, int>("Engine.HorsePower", 400);
bool result = predicate.Compile().Invoke(myCar);
```

IMO it would be useful if used with combination of the following extension methods

```
public static partial class Utils
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WherePropertyEquals<T, TValue>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyPath, TValue value)
    {
        return source.Where(PropertyEquals<T, TValue>(propertyPath, value));
    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> WherePropertyEquals<T, TValue>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string propertyPath, TValue value)
    {
        return source.Where(PropertyEquals<T, TValue>(propertyPath, value).Compile());
    }
}
```

so you can write something like this

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car> { myCar };
var cars400 = cars.WherePropertyEquals("Engine.HorsePower", 400).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to get the `property` value from an `object` with the nested property name as `string`

```
public static object GetNestedPropertyValue(object obj, string nestedDottedPropertyName)
{
    foreach (String part in nestedDottedPropertyName.Split('.'))
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;

        PropertyInfo info = obj.GetType().GetProperty(part);
        if (info == null)
            return null;

        obj = info.GetValue(obj, null);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

But this is not valid `Linq` statement

```
var engine = myCar.Select( c => c.Engine.HorsePower == 400 );
```

What you can do instead is, if you have a car object like this

```
var myCar = new Car()
{
    Engine = new Engine()
    {
        HorsePower = 400
    }
};
```

You can get the value of `Engine.HorsePower` as

```
var horsePower = (int)GetNestedPropertyValue(myCar, "Engine.HorsePower");
```

**Edit**

For a `Linq` example, if you have a `List<Car>` like this

```
var myCar2 = new Car()
{
    Engine = new Engine()
    {
        HorsePower = 800
    }
};
var cars = new List<Car> { myCar, myCar2 }; //myCar defined above
```

You can use `Linq` as

```
var car400 = cars.FirstOrDefault(c => (int)GetNestedPropertyValue(c, "Engine.HorsePower") == 400); //=> myCar
var horsePowers = cars.Select(c => (int)GetNestedPropertyValue(c, "Engine.HorsePower")); //=> 400, 800
```

Comment: Interesting! However, it needs to create my Expression dynamicly, since I don't know what's my List<> made of, it's a generic. Could you help implmenting your concept, with my PropertyEquals method?

Comment: A [Generic List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) in C# means you know the type. What you want to achieve with that list?